# Christmas lights: getting rid of the half that doesn't work?

Tags: electrical

We've all seen these regular Christmas light sets where only half of the lights work.

My question: assuming the half of the set that works is closest to the electric plug, is it possible to cut the half that doesn't work and rewire the ends?

I have about 5 sets of Christmas lights that only half of it work, and the half that works is the one closest to the electric plug. I don't want to throw them away, but I also don't want to go through the hassle of "hiding" the half that doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the fuses?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how they are wired. Many strings have two (or more) "parallel" strings of "series-connected" bulbs.  Since each of the series strings are independent, then other parallel strings can be safely removed.  Remember to carefully insulate the cut ends so that you don't electrocute someone.

[image: series-parallel lamp string]